# Visual Studio 2017 issue using translation resource files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resource-files

I think there is a bug in Visual Studio 2017 with generating resource files. I have created a simple project that does the following in VS2017 and VS2012

```
   namespace RSLanguageTranslationTester
    {
        class Program
     {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               while (true) // Loop indefinitely
               {
                    Console.WriteLine("Internal" + Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("TEST", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")));
                    Console.WriteLine("Internal" + Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("TEST", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es")));
                    Console.WriteLine("Internal" + Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("TEST", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de")));
                    if (Console.ReadLine() == "q") // Check string
                    {
                         break;
                    }            
               }
          }
     }
}
```

On 2012 i get the output 
This is English
This is German
This is Spanish

On 2017 I get the output
This is English
This is English
This is English

The two projects are identical, the resource files are set to public and the custom tool is set to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator in both projects. Does anyone have any experience of this? Its a .net 3.5 project as it needs to be imported into reporting services 2008 R2.

Folder structure is

```
Resources
-->Resource1.de.resx
-->Resource1.es.resx
-->Resource1.resx
Program.cs
```

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and I think this is in fact to do with .net 3.5. If I change to .net 4.0 project it works on both versions.

Comment: I think this is the issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5735/when-vs-2017-rc-is-installed-resourcesdll-is-gener.html